# Show that $E(|Y|) <\infty$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Consider two independent experiments. First: a biased coin is flipped with
$P(H) = \alpha$. Second: a sequence of Bernoulli trials is performed until the first success,
with $p$ being probability of success in each trial. Let $X$ be the total number of trials in
the second experiment and define a random variable $Y$ as

$$
Y = 
\begin{cases} 
  X  & \text{if coin shows $H$} \\
 -X  & \text{if coin shows $T$}
\end{cases}
$$

b) Show that $E(|Y|) <\infty$ and compute $E(Y)$

I can understand that $X $ is geometric and I could probably compute $E(Y)$ by myself but how does one show that $E(|Y|) <\infty$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not obvious that $\mathsf E(\lvert Y\rvert)=\mathsf E(X)$, then let $H$ be the indicator random variable of the coin result .   So by the Total Probability Theorem:

$$\begin{align} \mathsf E(\lvert Y\rvert) & = \mathsf E(\lvert Y\rvert\mid H{=}1)\,\mathsf P(H{=}1)+\mathsf E(\lvert Y\rvert\mid H{=}0)\,\mathsf P(H{=}0) \\ & = \alpha \mathsf E(X)+(1-\alpha)\mathsf E(X)\\ & = \mathsf E(X)\end{align}$$

Similarly, we can find that:

$$\begin{align} \mathsf E(Y) & = \mathsf E(Y\mid H{=}1)\,\mathsf P(H{=}1)+\mathsf E(Y \mid H{=}0)\,\mathsf P(H{=}0) \\ & = \alpha \mathsf E(X)-(1-\alpha)\mathsf E(X)\\ & = (2\alpha-1)\mathsf E(X)\end{align}$$

Comment: thats what I thought thank you!

Comment: E(Y) = E(|Y|) right?

Comment: No, @AlexChavez . $\mathsf E(Y) = (2\alpha -1)\mathsf E(X)$ and  $\mathsf E(\lvert Y\rvert)=\mathsf E(X)$.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, $|Y| = X$, since $X$ is positive, so $E(|Y|) = E(X)$.